# Ruby on Rails installation: config.gem not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Installed rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p358.exe, then tried to install [jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/#installation), but the config.gem command isn't being recognized. Interestingly I have no file called *environment.rb* on my drive.

Also I've never used ruby :D

```
H:\>gem install jammit
Fetching: Platform-0.4.0.gem (100%)
WARNING: Platform-0.4.0 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Fetching: open4-1.3.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: POpen4-0.1.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: yui-compressor-0.9.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: jammit-0.6.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed Platform-0.4.0
Successfully installed open4-1.3.0
Successfully installed POpen4-0.1.4
Successfully installed yui-compressor-0.9.6
Successfully installed jammit-0.6.5
5 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for Platform-0.4.0...
Installing ri documentation for open4-1.3.0...
Installing ri documentation for POpen4-0.1.4...
Installing ri documentation for yui-compressor-0.9.6...
Installing ri documentation for jammit-0.6.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for Platform-0.4.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for open4-1.3.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for POpen4-0.1.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for yui-compressor-0.9.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for jammit-0.6.5...


H:\>config.gem "jammit"
'config.gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

H:\>
```

Comment: Um, why are you trying to run "config.gem" as a command? Please read a basic rails tutorial if you want to understand rails (probably should learn and understand ruby first). "config.gem" is a rails configuration parameter, and has nothing to do with the command line. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well its pretty simple, the instructions I was following didn't explain the shift in context from the command line, to the config file in such a way that someone who has never used Ruby would understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a Rails app before you can do:

> Add the gem to Rails' environment.rb inside of the initializer:
>   config.gem "jammit"

`config.gem` is not a command rahter it is an entry in the `environment.rb` file.

To create a rails app go to your source folder and do:

```
rails new <app_name> # replace <app_name> with whatever you want to call your app
```

It will create a barebones rails app in a folder with the name that you chose for the app. Inside that folder you will find a config folder and in that folder you will see 'environment.rb`

Comment: ah cool, thanks! I didn't think the instructions I had were assuming knowledge - I'll look into it

Comment: also `config.gem` sounds like a line that would be in a Rails 2.x, sounds like you are looking at old instructions, Rails 3.x handles gem dependencies differently